# Semantics of returning arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop

When I create a method to determine what value I want to return, usually I can return a value directly - like so:

`return 0;`

However, I've discovered that when returning arrays, I have to create a *new instance* of an array, and return it - like so:

`String[] rtnArr = {"str1", "str2"};
return rtnArr;`

Why is this? Am I creating two arrays here, or am I only specifying a type when I instantiate the method?

Edit: I should clarify that I am returning one or another array based on a preliminary condition. That is to say, I have a switch and each case returns an array of *different* strings.

Comment: This depends on how you're getting or building the data in the array to begin with.  Sometimes you do build a new array; other times you can export it from a collection.  How are you building this data out?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35703309/982161

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating two arrays. Array initializers are only allowed when initiating a variable, so you can't use them directly in a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a variable to return an array. You can also return an array like this

```
return new String[] {"Hello", "World"};
```

When you declare an array you can initialize it as `String test[] = {"Hello", "World"};` because the array is obviously a string array so you don't need to do `new String[] {"Hello", "World"}`, but otherwise, you need an explicit initialization of the array with a type for type safety.

Answer (score 0):

> I've discovered that when returning arrays, I have to create a new instance of an array, and return it Why is this ? Am I creating two arrays here, or am I only specifying a
>   type when I instantiate the method ?

You don't need to `return` a new instance of the array always, sometimes you might need to `return` an existing array object as shown in the below code:

```
public class MyArrayTest {

     private String[] myArray;

     public MyArrayTest(String[] myArray) {
         this.myArray = myArray;
     }

     public String[] getMyArray() {
         return myArray;//returning existing array object
     }
}
```